# set const in controller and call in view as dropdown list in yii

Tags: yii, constants

I have three const in controller:

```
const TEST1 = 1;
const TEST2 = 2;
const TEST3 = 3;
```

How I can call these values in view as a dropDown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will get messy with all constants you have in diferent models, you can use code snippet I wrote to manage them. Please see [Managing constants easily](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/288/managing-constants-easily/) (yii wiki article)

I will copy just function and one example, but for full wiki and details please go visit link above.

Put this method in parent class or your model class directly:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {
    const TEST_1 = 1;
    const TEST_2 = 2;
    const TEST_3 = 3;


    /*
        Get class constants by token.
        If you set constants with same prefix, like:
        TEST_1
        TEST_2
        TEST_3

        , you can get it by calling
        Class::getConstants('TEST_');
    */
    public static function getConstants($token,$objectClass) {
        $tokenLen = strlen($token);

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($objectClass); //php built-in 
        $allConstants = $reflection->getConstants(); //constants as array

        $tokenConstants = array(); 
        foreach($allConstants as $name => $val) {
        if ( substr($name,0,$tokenLen) != $token ) continue;
        $tokenConstants[ $val ] = $val;
        }
        return $tokenConstants;
    }

}
```

And after that you can use this method to get specific constants (from one group) in array:

```
self::getConstants('TEST_',__CLASS__); //inside same class
ActiveRecord::getConstants('TEST_','ActiveRecord'); //outside, somewhere else in view or controller
```

For dropdown it would be looking as (if MyModel have parent ActiveRecord)

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('name','selected',
    MyModel::getConstants('TEST_','MyModel'),
    array(// for htmlOptions
    )
);
```

Now you can forget to edit all places in code if you adding new constant. It will automaticaly added to all your dropdowns or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just use:

```
$this::TEST1;
```

In dropdownList:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('name','selected',
    array($this::TEST1=>'Test1',$this::TEST2=>'Test2',$this::TEST3=>'Test3'),
    array(// for htmlOptions
    )
);
```